# How to assert that a object property is not present using python?

Tags: python

i want to assert in python that the object has no particular field.

i have an object like below,

```
output = {
    'username': 'user',
    'hidden_fields': {
         'name': 'name1',
    }
}
```

but sometimes this hidden_fields property might not be there. so the object is like so,

```
output = {
    'username': 'user'
}
```

now how can i assert that output object has no property hidden_fields.

i am new to python. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: `assert 'hidden_fields' not in output`?

Comment: if you want to assert (so raise exception) when the output doesn't include `hidden_fields` you can do so : 
`assert "hidden_fields" in output`

Answer (score 0):

Beware: You are handling a `dict` here, which is not exactly the same as an object.

To solve your problem, you could use this snippet:

```
if 'hidden_fields' not in output:
    print('No hidden fields')
else:
    print('Hidden fields found!')
```